# mysql Explicitly reference table.column in where clause

Tags: mysql

Is there any reason why MySQL is not liking the following explicit reference in my where clause.

where [table].[column] ?

I am getting an error Invalid query: Unknown column 'plugin_thold_log.id' in 'where clause'

this works in TSQL.

'plugin_thold_log is a table in my database and id is obviously a column in that same table.

my full query:

here is my full query:

```
select pl.id as id, 
from_unixtime(pl.time) as time,
case
when TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,(select from_unixtime(a.time) from plugin_thold_log a where a.id < plugin_thold_log.id and a.time >= '$dateStart' and a.time <= '$dateEnd' order by a.id desc LIMIT 1),from_unixtime(pl.time)) is null then 1
when TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,(select from_unixtime(a.time) from plugin_thold_log a where a.id < plugin_thold_log.id and a.time >= '$dateStart' and a.time <= '$dateEnd' order by a.id desc LIMIT 1),from_unixtime(pl.time)) > 30 then 1
when TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,(select from_unixtime(a.time) from plugin_thold_log a where a.id < plugin_thold_log.id and a.time >= '$dateStart' and a.time <= '$dateEnd' order by a.id desc LIMIT 1),from_unixtime(pl.time)) < 30
    and TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,(select from_unixtime(a.time) from (select from_unixtime(a.time) from plugin_thold_log a where a.id < plugin_thold_log.id and a.time >= '$dateStart' and a.time <= '$datEend' order by a.id desc LIMIT 7) a order by 1 asc LIMIT 1),from_unixtime(pl.time)) < 30 then 0
when TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,(select from_unixtime(a.time) from plugin_thold_log a where a.id < plugin_thold_log.id and a.time >= '$dateStart' and a.time <= '$dateEnd' order by a.id desc LIMIT 1),from_unixtime(pl.time)) < 30
    and TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,(select from_unixtime(a.time) from (select from_unixtime(a.time) from plugin_thold_log a where a.id < plugin_thold_log.id and a.time >= '$dateStart' and a.time <= '$datEend' order by a.id desc LIMIT 7) a order by 1 asc LIMIT 1),from_unixtime(pl.time) ) is null then 0
else 1
end
from
plugin_thold_log pl

where
pl.time >= '$dateStart'
and pl.time <= '$dateEnd'
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce the problem, test code works as expected:

```sql
/*Table structure for table `plugin_thold_log` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `plugin_thold_log`;

CREATE TABLE `plugin_thold_log` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

/*Data for the table `plugin_thold_log` */

INSERT  INTO `plugin_thold_log`(`id`) VALUES (NULL);

SELECT `id`
FROM `plugin_thold_log`
WHERE `plugin_thold_log`.`id` = 1;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6133b/1)</kbd>

**UPDATE**

```
/*
Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'plugin_thold_log.id' in 'where clause'

SELECT
    (   SELECT `id`
        FROM `plugin_thold_log` `a`
        WHERE `a`.`id` != `plugin_thold_log`.`id`
    )
FROM `plugin_thold_log` `pl`;
*/
```

Change:

```
SELECT
    (   SELECT `id`
        FROM `plugin_thold_log` `a`
        WHERE `a`.`id` != `pl`.`id`
    )
FROM `plugin_thold_log` `pl`;
```

Comment: Thanks wchiquito still getting the same unknown column error :(